# Recreate the same animation every time a button is pressed. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an animation that was executed when I click the button. I would like this animation to occur every time I click on this button. How can I achieve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/8jmnpn2u/2/

```
  <div id='div1'></div>
  <br>
  <button ng-click='show()'>show</button>

  $scope.show= function(){
    document.getElementById('div1').classList.add('animate');
  }


  div{
   display:inline-block;
   background:yellow;
   width:250px;
   height: 250px;
   transition: all linear 1s;
   opacity:0;
  }

  div.animate{
   opacity:1;
  }
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? Will you accept the answer? If not, will you further describe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since the animation uses CSS and is applied when your JavaScript adds the `animate` class, you'll want to remove the class, possibly wait for the animation to fade out, then re-add the class.

You would just amend your function to `.remove('animate')` first, then put the `.add('.animate')` line inside of a 'setTimeout()' function as needed:

```
$scope.show= function(){
  document.getElementById('div1').classList.remove('animate');
  setTimeout( function(){ document.getElementById('div1').classList.add('animate'); }, 2000); 
};
```